# Origem do uso da Canção do Exílio para mnemônico matemático

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica

Já é fato conhecido, pelo menos no Brasil, para qualquer um que tenha se envolvido com trigonometria no segundo grau, a rima da soma de seno:

> Minha terra tem palmeiras onde canta o sabiá
>
> Seno a Cosseno b, Seno b Cosseno a

Ou seja, sen(a+b) = sena*cosb + senb*cosa, mas isso é o bastante com a matemática.

Minha pergunta é: Qual o registro mais antigo dessa expressão?

Disclaimer: Eu passei horas pesquisando, esgotei todo meu "google-fu" e não encontrei nada, talvez os livros possam revelar mais coisas.

Comment: Difícil saber quem inventou essa fórmula mnemônica ou mesmo quando foi inventada.  Não são só os professores que inventam métodos de memorização. Alunos também o fazem.  Eu também fazia. Posso dizer que conheço essa fórmula para o "Seno a Cosseno b, Seno b Cosseno a" há mais de 40 anos.

Comment: Um professor meu de 60 anos disse que já usavam na época dele.
Eu entendo que essa pergunta vai incluir um pouco de deliberação da parte dos usuários, eu acho que seria propício a gente questionar os professores de matemática mais antigos

Comment: Achei ISSO: http://noticias.terra.com.br/vestibular/interna/0,,OI3132602-EI11636,00-Aprenda+portugues+e+matematica+cantando.html

Comment: @Lambie    É exatamente isso.  Só que não foi esse tal professor Daniel quem foi buscar "A Canção do Exílio" para servir de macete.  Eu, que "já não sou mais criança" (rs) aprendi esse macete quando estudei trigonometria.

Comment: O registro mais antigo, se existir, você deve procurar em arquivos históricos... Fora disso acho que ficaremos numa disputa de qual o mais antigo tipo "quem chega mais longe", "quem joga a pedra mais pra trás". Contudo... arrisco dizer que não vai achar nada nestes arquivos (bem óbvio), de maneira que tudo que podemos fazer é especular...

Comment: Triste, mas é verdade. Estou organizando uma pesquisa de campo com meus colegas (que já estavam no projeto dessa pesquisa), marcaremos uma ida à Biblioteca Pública, mas vivo em Fortaleza, a Biblioteca é boa, mas certamente teríamos acesso à mais arquivos em SP, por exemplo.

Comment: adoro essas mnemónicas `:)` Lembra-me a do `Pitágoras de Siracusa / um dia disse aos netos / o quadrado da hipotenusa / é igual à soma do quadrado dos catetos`. Mas Pitágoras era de Samos, não de Siracusa.

Comment: Uau! Conheço desde o 1o. Ano do 2o. Grau, há mais de 40 anos!